# Get the starting and ending positions of the series in c3js

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to fetch the starting and last (x,y cordinates) of the series so that I can append to my chart. I have tried looking at the onRendered callback but been able to get only to the labels so far. Cant get my head around getting the actual x,y cordinates of the start of the series and the end of the series (start of the path and end of the path).

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sourabhtewari/94tbbyrd/27/

This code gives me the labels data

```
function onRendered() {
  console.log(this);


 d3.selectAll('.c3-text').each((v) => {
           console.dir(v);
        });

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by x, y coordinates? the pixel position of start/ending points? Or the pct, year-month of start/ending points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet to get first/last point for each path:

```
  var sel = d3.selectAll('.c3-line');
  console.log("sel:", sel);
  sel.each((v, i) => {
    var path = sel[0][i], 
    len = Math.floor( path.getTotalLength() );
    console.log("#:", i);
    console.log("path:", path);
    console.log("nr. points:", len);
    console.log("first point:", path.getPointAtLength(0));
    console.log("last point:", path.getPointAtLength(len-1));
  });
```

In fact `c3-line` is the class associated to series SVG path.

Check the fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/xzsq4t1z/